# Communication between MS Metro and an Arduino board?

Tags: microsoft-metro, arduino, windows-rt

I've received a project from someone that includes an Arduino (Uno) board with some sensors and lights with an USB cable and a documented protocol for communicating with this board through a COM port. It works fine with some existing code, but I need to port the whole project to a Windows RT environment using an ARM processor and including the Metro interface for the application. And it's going to be completely rewritten...
First of all, my Windows RT device does have an USB port so it can connect to the board. But the challenge is to communicate with the board to read out the sensors and manipulate the lights and I happen to have problems finding some useful libraries, tutorials or other information about how to make these work together.
This project works fine with other Windows versions, though. I just need something specific for Windows RT/ARM/Metro.

Comment: And no, I have no control over the Arduino board so I cannot alter it in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to do this on Windows RT, and [here](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/05/metro-answers-can-i-use-serial-port.html) is an explanation why. As a work around I am using a standard full screen WPF application in combination with the [Surface SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716) for touch enable UI components. The obvious disadvantage here is that you cannot publish the app to the store.

Answer (score 0):

I think that we should actually try it on a real machine instead of the rt. The surface rt is basically for documents and the internet.
You'd be better off trying all of this with a Toshiba 2032.
A PDA from about 2003.

Comment: Your response is two years late. I already have a new tablet. :-)